# GCC installation on Fedora 18 x86_64

Tags: gcc, x86-64, conflict

I've been trying to install gcc compiler but the installation stops and i get the following error advice:

```
file /usr/lib64/audit from install of glibc-2.16-30.fc18.x86_64 conflicts with file from package audit-2.2.1-2.fc18.x86_64
```

Could anybody help me please?
I did some searchs but couldn't fix it...

Thanks!

Comment: I fixed it.. If somebody faces the same problem just do the following:

As sudo type the command 'yum update audit'.
Just run again the command to install gcc and it will work :)

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked! Care to explain why or how though? Thanks.